# Python: How check if two or more given words are present in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-import, text-processing

I have a text file consider questions.txt, I wanted to check if all the 5 questions numbers are present or not

For example, if the file contains Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
 But not Q5  it should output as "Q5 not found"
or atleast as "not all questions found"

Basically I wanted to search if all the given words(question numbers)are present in the txt file or not

Comment: What's the definition of a question? I assume your file doesn't just contain literally "Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4"?

Comment: @FynnBecker Yes it does, like line 1- "Q1 : blah blah" line 2- "Q2 : blah blah" .... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

```
WORDS_TO_FIND = tuple("Q{}".format(i) for i in range(5))

with open('questions.txt') as file:
    text = file.read()
    for word in WORDS_TO_FIND:
        if word not in text:
            print("{} not found".format(word))
```

You could also use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) for more complicated patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the variable text as the `text` you'd like to search, I'd use:

```
oc_Q = re.findall(r'[Q][1-5]', text)
print (oc_Q)
```

oc_Q will contain all occurrences of the Q[1-5]s.